# What rule governs "panic->panicking" and why? Would it apply to all -ic verbs?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

It seems odd that the continual tense of "to panic" is "panicking". Or "picnic->picnicking". When did the "k" get added, and why? Surely the natural extension would be "paniccing" if one wished to preserve the hard "c" sound visually and avoid "-ici-" and its intuitive soft "c"?

Does that rule also apply to all verbs ending in -ic? For example if we had verbs "to lyric [a song]" or "to topic [a forum post]"? I can't think of other examples!

Comment: topicking sounds an odd word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that rule also apply to all verbs ending in -ic?

Yes.

There are very few verbs that end with *-ic* and almost all of them have the letter *k* in their progressive (-ing form) and participles (-ed form).

We add the letter *k* to their progressives and participles because we want the original pronunciation with the /k/ sound in their inflections. And if we don't add the letter *k*, the pronunciation will change (i.e. it will become /s/ rather /k/).

The letter *c* often gives the /k/ sound when it comes before the letters *a (e.g. car), o (e.g. cot)* or *u (e.g. cup)*, or *it's at the end (e.g. panic)*. Or when *it comes before the letter k (e.g. pick)*.

By contrast, it gives the /s/ sound when it comes before the letters *e (e.g. cent), i (e.g. city)* or *y (e.g. fluency)*.

*Panic* has the /k/, and if we don't add the letter *k* to its progressive or participle, its pronunciation will change from /k/ to /s/:

- *Panicing/paniced*: here the *c* comes before *i* and *e* respectively and will likely be pronounced /s/ rather than /k/.

Therefore, *mimic* becomes *mimicking/mimicked*, *frolic* becomes *frolicking/frolicked*, *traffic* becomes *trafficking/trafficked*, *magic* becomes *magicking/magicked* etc.

 And almost all other verbs that end with *-ic* have *-ck-* in their progressives and participles.

So the main purpose of adding the *k* is to keep the original pronunciation.

Comment: We use letters to represent sounds, not the other way around. So I'd say it's the reverse of what I described in my answer. The pronunciation is with the /k/ sound and we add the letter k to their spelling to match it with the pronunciation because <ck> often represents the /k/ sound.

Comment: it's probably unfortunate that original spelling of most of those was ending with `-ck`(including *panick*). After reform it became `-c`, but spelling in `-ing` form had remained.

Comment: There's also 'politicking', now defunct as a verb.

Comment: @PhilipWitt, There's also *havocked*, but it's been *archaicked*!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul could be related to the archaic forms of those words: panick, magick, etc.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul in case of havocking verb havock got some different meaning ( to let out a hunting, spooking cry?), to probably it's only a distant relation by etymology with havoc.

Answer (score 0):

It's the rule of adding endings to verb. Rules sounds like:

If the verb ends with a single vowel plus a consonant, and the stress is at the end of the word (e.g. *refer*), then you need to double the final consonant before adding *-ed* and *–ing*:

If the verb ends with a vowel plus a consonant and the stress is not at the end of the word, you don’t need to double the final consonant when adding *-ed* and *-ing*

Tf the verb has only one syllable and ends with a single vowel plus a consonant (e.g. *stop*), then you need to double the final consonant before adding *-ed* and *-ing*.

If the verb ends with two vowels plus a consonant, you should generally not double the final consonant.

**If the verb ends in -c (e.g. *panic*), you need to add a *-k* before adding *-ed* and -*ing*, and also *-er*.**